# Python json request shows a KeyError even though key exists

Tags: python, python-requests

This code works fine for a few lines and then I receive a KeyError. Why does this happen?

This is the code:

```
import time
import json
import requests

def liquiANTbids():
    return requests.get('https://api.liqui.io/api/3/depth/ant_btc').json()["ant_btc"]['bids'][0][0]

def liquiANTasks():
    return requests.get('https://api.liqui.io/api/3/depth/ant_btc').json()["ant_btc"]['asks'][0][0]

while True:
    print('Liqui ANTBTC Bid', liquiANTbids())
    print('Liqui ANTBTC Ask', liquiANTasks())

    time.sleep (2)
```

This is the output:

```
Liqui ANTBTC Bid 0.0001074
Liqui ANTBTC Ask 0.00010839
Liqui ANTBTC Bid 0.0001074
Liqui ANTBTC Ask 0.00010839
Liqui ANTBTC Bid 0.0001074

return requests.get('https://api.liqui.io/api/3/depth/ant_btc').json()["ant_btc"]['asks'][0][0]
KeyError: 'ant_btc'
>>>
```

JSON response:

```
{"ant_btc":{"asks":[[0.00010839,17.22110214],[0.00010923,32.20416557],[0.00010994,59.43151426],[0.00011065,59.01649751],[0.00011137,58.89761686],[0.000112,292.389],[0.00011209,0.91178343],[0.0001121,46.18439581],[0.00011282,57.50385724],[0.000113,292.389],[0.00011356,56.91214726],[0.0001143,56.91188603],[0.00011504,27.01634667],[0.00011579,56.20278728],[0.00011654,55.97049391],[0.0001173,55.51480614],[0.00011806,60.77063155],[0.00011883,60.86674399],[0.0001196,61.61144633],[0.00012037,0.84729334],[0.00012038,61.28390582],[0.00012475,24.27930138],[0.00013509,1.83984369],[0.0001351,5.0],[0.00013843,58.71327823],[0.00014,35.71428571],[0.00015999,1.86634765],[0.00016,31.24999999],[0.00017999,0.57529376],[0.00018,27.77777777],[0.00019999,1.43552721],[0.0002,19.64417044],[0.00039999,8.33067221],[0.0004,134.99999999],[0.00048888,3.0],[0.00053236,10.0],[0.00054658,2.63919448],[0.00055959,8.0],[0.0006,1041.417],[0.00061897,1.44669023],[0.00064,500.0],[0.00064522,500.0],[0.00065008,400.0],[0.00065235,5.03612838],[0.00065431,500.0],[0.00068579,363.08080944],[0.0007,219.78],[0.00072,3.40961662],[0.00073989,18.0],[0.00075999,0.24141163],[0.00076,46.21114368],[0.00081999,0.47316131],[0.00082,10.0],[0.00082355,27.12072458],[0.00087,50.0],[0.0008725,9.89104725],[0.0008746,0.12153569],[0.00087461,23.0],[0.00088,99.9],[0.00088888,5.0],[0.00089587,42.29449791],[0.00093739,0.48474448],[0.0009374,19.97],[0.00097,50.0],[0.00098888,3.0],[0.001,94.99429235],[0.00100686,0.13136847],[0.00100687,5.0],[0.00102,9.141],[0.0010511,0.22406918],[0.00105111,43.9769833],[0.00109,35.0],[0.00109999,0.145431],[0.0011,39.96],[0.00111,45.0],[0.00116999,0.33855555],[0.00117,4008.50026717],[0.0012,43.67484284],[0.00128999,0.40042593],[0.00129,35.68275862],[0.00138887,0.14103965],[0.00138888,4.865],[0.00149999,0.39271089],[0.0015,2.4925],[0.00150229,3.0],[0.00170228,0.44673393],[0.00170229,3.0],[0.00180229,3.0],[0.00190228,0.25466201],[0.00190229,5.0],[0.00220228,0.59325788],[0.00220229,5.0],[0.00226749,210.25247336],[0.00232521,994.722763],[0.00373037,0.02707501],[0.00373038,0.02707501],[0.00785936,3.66385611],[0.00785937,265.905828],[0.07893739,1.15304938],[0.0789374,10.0],[0.13903939,0.00072641]],"bids":[[0.0001074,25.02801671],[0.00010739,61.26924526],[0.0001067,61.7220646],[0.00010636,3.08618804],[0.00010601,61.15097194],[0.00010533,61.47210471],[0.00010522,34.65187227],[0.0001052,71.29277566],[0.000105,11.88],[0.00010493,8.436557],[0.00010465,62.24850491],[0.00010401,1.0039782],[0.000104,11.88],[0.00010397,62.62081392],[0.0001033,63.02216043],[0.00010263,63.43372388],[0.00010197,63.82231006],[0.00010131,64.23296823],[0.00010066,64.6154645],[0.0001002,74.7005988],[0.00010001,65.23957407],[0.00009936,65.47400079],[0.00009872,65.89406861],[0.00009808,66.1887969],[0.00009745,66.58600276],[0.00006001,17.74604323],[0.00006,40.0],[0.00000315,9523.8],[0.00000314,463.59241073],[0.000003,20000.0],[0.00000235,12765.9574468],[0.0000021,100.0],[0.00000101,2000.0],[0.00000022,50000.0],[0.00000021,2380.95238095],[0.0000001,9990.0],[0.00000002,23810.0]]}}
```

Comment: Well... the key doesn't exist... have you tried debugging by printing what the `.json()` response or status_code of the response is before attempting to access it?

Comment: can you please copy-paste the `.json()` response ?

Comment: Do you mean the whole response from the webpage?

Comment: the `response.json()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the server isn't quite stable or has rate-limiting techniques, and sometimes return other information than the desired data.

Here's my attempt at figuring this out:

```
wsl@MSI-GS73:~ $ python3
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17)
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> try:
...  while True:
...   r = requests.get("https://api.liqui.io/api/3/depth/ant_btc")
...   rr = r.json()["ant_btc"]
... except KeyError:
...  s = r
...
>>> s
<Response [200]>
>>> s.text
'{"success":0,"error":"not available"}'
>>>
```

What does the server return?

```
{"success":0,"error":"not available"}
```

That means you had better handle this "special data":

```
def liquiANTbids():
    r = requests.get('https://api.liqui.io/api/3/depth/ant_btc').json()
    if "success" in r and r["success"] == 0:
        raise ValueError("Request failed")
    return r["ant_btc"]['bids'][0][0]
```

Alternatively, you can add some delay in the loop so you don't get throttled, as given in [CodeIt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53802063/5958455).

Comment: Yea, I guess this makes sense. Thanks

Comment: @David I wanted to ask you why did you add the delay after the while loop in your original code.

Comment: I actually did add it in the while loop, just made a mistake when posting the question.

Comment: @David Adding the delay, really helps you to avoid getting errors. I'm still running the script almost for 10 minutes. It never throw any error.

Comment: @David According to the official [website](https://liqui.io/api) of Liqui API. It says * All information is cached every 2 seconds, so there's no point in making more frequent requests.*. So when 2 second delay is applied it will never show any error.

Comment: @CodeIt I'll try to use a larger delay. With the code suggested by iBug, it returns 'ValueError: Request failed' after a while.

Comment: @CodeIt Why keep questioning the OP when they've clarified that the 2-second delay was indeed in place and was not the cause?

Comment: The delay is not the cause, even with a 20 second or 60 second delay I still get the same error.

Comment: @David You may need to contact their official support. Since there is no rate limiting, then it should not throw any error. Support team may be able to help you fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that the json you receive sometimes might be empty.

Comment: Is this really an answer?

Comment: @iBug you presume it might be false?

Comment: I think it's wrong. If the server returns an empty string, then `.json()` would have raised a `ValueError` (or `json.decode.JSONDecodeError` starting from Python 3.5). Since `.json()` succeeded, the response from server must be a valid JSON string.

Comment: @iBug I never said empty string, I said empty json, that could mean `{}`.

Comment: Oh then it's my fault for misreading your answer. Good point.

Answer (score 0):

Here i guess you are using `time.sleep(2)` to create a 2 second delay between requests. But you are not actually doing it since you have placed it after the `while` loop. Place it inside the while loop. You can use the below code. I had tested it continuously for 5 minutes, it is working fine.

```
import time
import json
import requests

def liquiANTbids():
    return requests.get('https://api.liqui.io/api/3/depth/ant_btc').json()["ant_btc"]['bids'][0][0]

def liquiANTasks():
    return requests.get('https://api.liqui.io/api/3/depth/ant_btc').json()["ant_btc"]['asks'][0][0]

while True:
    print('Liqui ANTBTC Bid', liquiANTbids())
    print('Liqui ANTBTC Ask', liquiANTasks())
    time.sleep(2)
```

> According to Liqui API [website](https://liqui.io/api), it says *All information is cached every 2 seconds, so there's no point in making more frequent requests*. So adding 2 second delay should work fine.

Comment: nice one, delaying the requests so they don't get blocked.

Comment: Note on this answer: The OP has [clarified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53801998/python-json-request-shows-a-keyerror-even-though-key-exists/53802055?noredirect=1#comment94452991_53802055) that the 2-second delay was actually inside the loop, and it was not the cause of the unexpected response from Liqui API.

Comment: @iBug If it was in place then you will not see that error. I had tested it buddy.

Comment: I understand that you tested it, but people's environment may be different, especially network connectivity. Just because it isn't the case for you doesn't mean it's the same for others. Maybe you should respect OP's response? They [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53801998/python-json-request-shows-a-keyerror-even-though-key-exists/53802055?noredirect=1#comment94453302_53802055) that 20 secs or even 1 minute doesn't help.

Comment: @CodeIt huh? What do I have to do with this discussion?

Comment: @andreihondrari Sorry friend. I tagged the wrong person.